# Are there any differences between qRT-PCR and GEO (microarray data from NCBI) regarding dealing with internal control genes?

Tags: microarray

As we know, when we do qRT-PCR, the two most commonly used methods are absolute quantification and relative quantification, both the methods are involved in dealing with normalization of house-keeping genes or internal control genes (like GAPDH, Actin). In the microarray experiments, the similar normalization should also be adopted (I did not have any experimence with this kind of experiment). But I do know that someone obtained GEO file from NCBI, and simply did t-test analysis to find differenced expressed genes without any operation with the internal control genes. So I wander whether this is the right way, if not, what should we do with internal control genes to normalize data?

Comment: did you find an answer to your question? If you did, it would be great if you could post it here for people having similar questions in future